# In MediaWiki, how to permanently delete old versions of deleted pages?

Tags: mediawiki

I have deleted tens of thousands of spam pages in a MediaWiki instance painstakingly. Now I realize the old versions of those pages still occupy database space and present a kind of garbage in the MediaWiki.  How to efficiently delete those old versions?

Answer (score 2):

I presume, deleted articles have now a status `archived`, because if article is deleted by admin, it s removed into `archive` db-table.

**This solution is for real admins:**

- Read firstly [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3AMaintenance_scripts) manual.
- Then prepare and run [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3ADeleteArchivedRevisions.php) maintenance script.

**This solution is for bloody rookies:**

- Go into the database with your db-manager of choice,
- mark all items in the `archive` table and delete them.